# На роль или для роли

Tags: предлоги

Будьте добры, подскажите, какой предлог уместен:
"Лидера не так нужно выбирать. Саша слишком легкомысленна. Она не подходит на эту роль / для этой роли".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае лучше остановиться на таком варианте:

***Лидера не так нужно выбирать. Саша слишком легкомысленна. Она не подходит  для этой роли.***

Речь идет о качествах, необходимых **для роли** лидера. Нельзя сказать: Саша слишком легкомысленна на эту роль.

Answer (score 1):

*На эту роль* - роль в театре или кино во время кастинга, конкретная вакансия.

*Для этой роли* - для всех остальных случаев.

Если под "лидером" имеется ввиду вакансия начальника, то лучше "на эту роль".